# Sequencing rtPCR product

Tags: dna-sequencing

So I have a validated set of primers for rtPCR from Biorad that contains SYBR green.  If I do rtPCR, can I use the rtPCR product after purifying it with a Qiagen PCR purification kit?  Also, I'm under the impression that the sequencing company needs primers to do sequencing, do I just use the PCR primer or one of the "universal" primers the company has?

Comment: Theoretically, you will still end up with a specific PCR amplicon, so you can sequence it with the same primers used for rt-PCR. By the way, do you mean real-time or reverse transcriptase PCR?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PCR purification kit for cleaning up the DNA.

You can use the primers that you used for RTPCR for sequencing. The universal primers would work only if the sequence complementary to it is there in the 3' end of your amplicon.